# Unauthorized when trying to call Sharepoint 2016 from ASP.NET

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, authentication, iis, 401

I have a piece of code that uses CSOM to get search results from Sharepoint.

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(serverUrl)
{
    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
})
{
    var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
    keywordQuery.QueryText = query;
    var searchExecutor = new SearchchExecutor(clientContext);
    var results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

This code works when it's executed on the Sharepoint server locally, when I'm logged in.

However if I put this piece of code in an web application hosted on IIS, I get 401 Unauthorized on `ExecuteQuery()`

EDIT:

I also tried using the HttpClient like this:

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true
})
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        var requri = new Uri("https://sharepoint.mydomain.com.pl/_api/search/query");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requri);
    }
}
```

This also gets me 401 error.

But when I tried the "https://sharepoint.mydomain.com.pl/sites/search/_api/search/query" I got a different error:
`Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchServiceException: "The SafeQueryPropertiesTemplateUrl \"The SafeQueryPropertiesTemplateUrl &quot;{0}&quot; is not a valid URL.\" is not a valid URL."` but I found out that this is likely to be an unauthorized error as well.

What's interesting, both cases (calling the main site collection ('/') or the search site collection ('sites/search') on IIS Express environment works.

The Windows authentication is enabled in IIS application settings
[image]

as well as in Sharepoint Central administration
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of authenticating with the default credentials, we need to pass the credential explicitly using the **NetworkCredential** where we need to pass the **username** and **password**.

**Connect to SharePoint from Asp. Net using NetworkCredential:**

```
using (srcContext = new  ClientContext("siteURL"))
  { 
     string userName="MyUserName"
     string password="MyPassword"
     NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password); 
}
```

Comment: Well, that's not an option. I have integrated authentication enabled on my site and I need to reuse it for the Sharepoint connection.

Comment: What account are you using for the application pool of the Web Application where this code is running? Does that account have permission to your SharePoint site?

Comment: @Szybki if this is multihop (client-webserver-SharePoint) then Windows authentication isn’t enough.  You need to set up Kerberos Auth (as NTLM cannot double-hop).  You’ll need SPNs set up alto match the host names and accounts used for your SharePoint site and your website.

Comment: @GregW I've set SPN like this: `setspn -U -S HTTP/server-name domain\username` where `server-name` is the name of the server where both sharepoint and my webapp is running and the `username` is the name of the account used to run the sharepoint application pool. 
@MatiurRahman the account has an access to the sharepoint.
But I'm still getting 401. Do I need to set up some additional permission for the account? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Is the account running the website the same as the account running the SharePoint site?  Your SPN should be set to the hostname of each website (without the port number).  Is the hostname the same for your web site and SharePoint site?  Since it’s the same server, you could also be running into loop back prevention if you’re not using the server’s name to connect.

Comment: @GregW No, the accounts are different. I think the SPNs are set correctly. How can I check it? Could you please see the edited question? I added different approach with somewhat different behavior but in the end I still end up with 401.

Comment: @Szybki Just to clarify.  You have two websites under the one hostname but running under different app pools with different identities?

Comment: @GregW Yes, they are even on different machines. SharePoint web app is running under a pool with a dedicated domain account and the application is running on a different machine under a pool with the app pool account.

Comment: @Szybki You only need to add a SPN if you're not using the computer name and/or you're not using the machine account.
For your SharePoint server, the SPN would look like:
setspn -S http/sharepoint.mydomain.com.pl <user account app pool is running as>
For your webserver (running as app pool identity):
setspn -S http/<fqdn of web server> <computername>